# Must a question have a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Simple enough? Since everything here is about straight precise questions and straight precise answers, should there be a question in every question?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721364/when-im-mousedown-on-panel-mousemove-through-child-element-not-works?noredirect=1#comment24075257_16721364), where the users asks in 2 steps, brought me here.

- This does not work.
- This is my code.

Yes we can understand what is happening but there is no question *per se*. So yeah..  Must a question have a question?

Comment: Yes, it should. It might just be "Why does this give (generic error 500bajillion)," but it's too easy for there to be multiple issues in a problem.

Comment: There is an implied question, "How do I fix my code to solve this problem?"  If the OP has an implied question but doesn't state it explicitly, one can always add it.  Even if you don't bother to do that, it's important to recognize that a question still exists, it's just not explicitly stated.

Comment: @Servy So asking the OP to add a question to his post is wrong in the case where the question is implied ?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk I didn't say that.  I think it's perfectly acceptable.  If the OP has difficulty doing so it's an indication of a much more significant problem.  The point is what you're effectively asking them to do is make their question clearer, rather than asserting there is no question at all.  If you were trying to close it as NARQ then I'd disagree with that.

Comment: If the implied question is obvious, calling out the OP for not stating it in the form of a question might seem pedantic or bureaucratic.

Comment: @Juhana I'm not opposed to asking them to include the question in the question.  I agree that chastising them for only implying a question probably isn't proper (as long as the question really is clear).  Saying something more along the lines of, "Could you please state your question explicitly so that it's clearer exactly what you have a problem with?" might have been the more constructive comment to make.

Comment: @Servy No not at all. I see the *implied* question. But an argument in the comment section got me wondering if it was mandatory to have a clear question in the post.I guess the problem is how I asked for it to the OP. Now I know thanks.

Comment: I agree with @Servy.  Making that comment more clear and constructive is what makes it acceptable.  If something is unclear, be specific about what you want clarified.  If it's obvious what the question is, feel free to edit it into the question for the OP if it bothers you.

Comment: The real problem is not the lack of a literal question. The problem with this and thousands of similar questions is that the OP does not explain what he has tried or researched so far.

Comment: Oh the irony -- posts a Meta question about a rule he thinks exists, then gets it closed for a rule that actually does.

Comment: @tnw well this happens pretty much everytime someone gets closed as duplicate on meta...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the post contains no question, we are required to guess. Sometimes the intended question is obvious. Sometimes it just *seems* to be obvious, and we waste a lot of cycles answering something that the OP isn't asking.

Everyone benefits if the OP is clear about what is really needed, and direct questions are the way to provide that clarity. For that reason, I almost always ask the OP to provide a specific question.

This is a typical request:

> Will you clarify your goal? What do you expect to happen, what is currently happening, and what problems have you encountered that prevent you from accomplishing it?

This can be trimmed as needed if the OP provided partial information.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly how I see it. I guess asking the OP `where is the question ? ` was unclear and made the other users thought that I saw this as NARQ. I will ask to formulate a clear question next time.

Answer (score -1):

Stemmed from a discussion here: [Why am I not getting any MouseMove events while the mouse button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721364/when-im-mousedown-on-panel-mousemove-through-child-element-not-works?noredirect=1#comment24075702_16721364)

I say no, not necessarily. From that question, it's quite obvious what the poster's question is.

There's no need to indirectly tackle the issue that some posters have: no clear objective in a question. As long as you're able to answer, "What is their question?" by looking at their post, there's no need for an explicit question.

Is it good practice? Yes. Should it be required? No.

Answer (score -2):

No.

When the teacher and the whole class stares at you when you come late,it is deemed that they are asking you a question(why you are late) even without asking a question.

Comment: Even in this situation, the question isn't clear. Maybe they have been discussing a classroom theft and had concluded that you were the culprit. Maybe they were expecting someone else to walk in the door at that precise time, and were glaring pre-emptively.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Well played.